# Something wrong when I use the Dataloader

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

The phrase which pre_proceed the dataset

```
class data_test(Dataset):
def __init__(self,data_root,transform=None):
    data_image=glob.glob(data_root+'/*.jpg')

    self.data_image=data_image
    self.transform=transform

def __getitem__(self, index):
    data_image_path=self.data_image[index]

    image_data=cv2.imread(data_image_path,-1) # unchanged
    if self.transform:
        image_data=self.transform(image_data)

    return image_data
```

The above operation is ordinary, but when I load the dataset,

```
`dataset=data_test(train_dataset,transforms)
data=DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=8,num_workers=0)
for idx,data in enumerate(data):
    print(data.shape)`
```

an error occur,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually pretty specific on the error, the error that was raised is [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError). You are supposed to implement the `__len__` function in your custom dataset.

In your case that would be as simple as (assuming `self.data_image` contains all your dataset instances) adding this function to the `data_test` class:

```
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_image)
```